# How to extract text with fixed length in delimited file

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I want to extract a field from a delimited file.

Below is the content of my file -

```
A,B,C,"01/02/2015,01/03/2016,02/26/2017",01,56
A,B,G,"01/02/2012,01/03/2011,02/26/2010",01,56
```

I want to retrieve only the first date in each line and replace the entire column with that value.

output

```
A,B,C,01/02/2015,01,56
A,B,G,01/02/2012,01,56
```

I know that I can split the value in "s to comma separated values, but not sure how limit only the first value and omit the others.

Please guide me for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/"\([^,]*\)[^"]*"/\1/'
```

I.e. find a double quote, remember what follows it up to a comma, and replace that up to the following double quote with the remembered part.

For more serious work with CSV, see Perl and [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS).

Comment: if you wish you may add this too, more or less same, in gawk `awk '{print gensub(/"([^,]*).*"/,"\\1","")}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample if yes then following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F',|"' '{print $1,$2,$5,$(NF-1),$NF}' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A,B,01/02/2015,01,56
A,B,01/02/2012,01,56
```

***Explanation:***

`-F',|"'`: Setting field separator as either `,` or `"` for each line of Input_file here.

`print`: `print` is out of the box `awk` keyword that prints lines/variables etc.

`$1,$2,$5,$(NF-1),$NF`: Printing `$1`(first field of current line), `$2`(second field of current line), `$5`(fifth field of current line),`$(NF-1)`(seconf last field of current line) and `$NF`(last field of current line).

`OFS=,`: Setting output field separator as comma here.

`Input_file`: Mentioning the Input_file name here.

Comment: Bare in mind that field 4 is empty as it is located between `,"`

Comment: @kvantour, I have not mentioned 4th column in code.

Comment: I know, it was a general comment indicating this subtlety just in case if somebody was wondering why `$5` and not `$4`